# creating gabor texture in c#

Tags: c#, textures, opentk

I am trying to create a texture (in a 3-D byte array) that is a coloured gabor patch. I am using OpenTK to map the texture. The texture mapping is working fine, but the texture that is created by my code below is not what I need.

The code I have come up with is as follows:

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                    {
                        double sin_term = 0.5*(double)Math.Sin(10 * 3.14159 * ((double)x / (double)size));
                        sin_term += 0.5;
                        double gauss = 0.5+Math.Exp(-((Math.Pow(x,2)+Math.Pow(y,2))/(2*Math.Pow(sigma,2))));
                        double gabor = sin_term * gauss;
                        byteTexture2[j,i,0] = (byte)(((double)Colour.R * gabor));
                        byteTexture2[j,i,1] = (byte)(((double)Colour.G * gabor));
                        byteTexture2[j,i,2] = (byte)(((double)Colour.B * gabor));
                    }
                }
```

My maths isn't alll that good, so I may be off track but I was trying to multiply the sine wave by the gaussian. The sine wave term seems to work OK by itself but the gaussian may be where it is having problems.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Have found MATLAB code for this problem but no c/c++/c# code

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently coded up a Gabor filter kernel for use in OpenCV (using C++). Here is my code for the kernel:

```
/// compute Gabor filter kernels
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++){
   x = i - 0.5*(h - 1);
   for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
      y = j - 0.5*(h - 1);
      gaborKernelCos.at<float>(i, j) = exp((-16 / (h*h))*(x*x + y*y))*cos((2 * M_PI*w / h)*(x*cos(q) + y*sin(q))) / (h*h);
      gaborKernelSin.at<float>(i, j) = exp((-16 / (h*h))*(x*x + y*y))*sin((2 * M_PI*w / h)*(x*cos(q) + y*sin(q))) / (h*h);
   }
}
```

Where the input parameters are the kernel size `h`, wave number `w`, and filter orientation `q`. Note the wave number is related to the filter pixel wavelength by `l = h/w`. Also, my value for `sigma` is simply a constant multiple of `h`.

This shouldn't really produce anything wildly different from your code as far as I can tell. Does your value for `sigma` make sense? It should probably be at most `sigma = 0.5*size`.